# Network Stream does not Write data

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm trying to read and write data from a TCP Server with the following code.

```
cs1.witsStream = new NetworkStream(cs1.witsClient.Client);

Byte[] receive_bytes = new Byte[256];
Int32 bytes = cs1.witsStream.Read(receive_bytes, 0, receive_bytes.Length);
cs1.tempData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive_bytes, 0, bytes);
d_in.Text = cs1.tempData;

if (cs1.witsStream.CanWrite == true)
{
      string send_data = "0105000";
      byte[] send_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send_data);
      cs1.witsStream.Write(send_bytes,0,send_bytes.Length);
}

cs1.witsStream.Close();
```

The reading part works fine with no error. But the writer fails to work. There is no exception thrown.

Already tried: Flush stream before write, Use another stream to write and WriteAsync, WriteByte. All fail to write data.

Also tried to send data from another program to the said server and it reads fine, to isolate any server side issue.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Just checking, cs1.witsStream.CanWrite is true? Should you add a log statement after the check just to be sure the code is executing?

Comment: Yes, the "cs1.witsStream.CanWrite" is returns true.

Comment: Tricky one.. I've set up a test TCP server, the code works for me, nothing immediately obvious anyhow.